# Android native C function as variable?

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

So, I'm working with a library that uses a callback function that is configured and called when it's needed. I need to access local variables in my c function from inside that function and can't make them members of the parent class for other reasons.

So, essentially this is my set up

**callback.h**

```
typedef void handler_func(uint8_t *data, size_t len);

typedef struct my_cfg {
    handler_func *handler;
} my_cfg;
```

**otherfile.c**

```
#include "callback.h"

void test() {
    char *test = "This is a test";

    my_cfg cfg = { 0 };
    memset(&cfg, 0, sizeof(my_cfg));

    my_cfg.handler = my_handler;

    // This is just an example, basically
    // elsewhere in the code the handler
    // function will be called when needed.
    load_config(my_cfg);
}

void my_handler(uint8_t *data, size_t len) {
    // I need to access the `test` var here.
}
```

What I need is something like this:

```
#include "callback.h"

void test() {
    final char *test = "This is a test";

    my_cfg cfg = { 0 };
    memset(&cfg, 0, sizeof(my_cfg));

    // This is the type of functionality I need. 
    my_cfg.handler = void (uint8_t *data, size_t len) {
        printf("I can now access test! %s", test);
    };

    // This is just an example, basically
    // elsewhere in the code the handler
    // function will be called when needed.
    load_config(my_cfg);
}
```

Please keep in mind that I **cannot** change the header files that define the function definition for `handler_func`, nor can I modify the `my_cfg` struct, nor can I modify the area of the code that is calling the `handler_func`, `my_cfg.handler`. They are all internal in the library.

(Also note that there may be code errors above, this is all psuedo code technically. I'm not at my computer, just typing this all out free hand on a tablet)

**Edit**

From what I understand, nested functions would solve this issue. But it appears that clang doesn't support nested functions.

Reference: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#gcc-extensions-not-implemented-yet

> clang does not support nested functions; this is a complex feature
>   which is infrequently used, so it is unlikely to be implemented
>   anytime soon.

Is there another work around?

Comment: Do you have to use the same callback function in multiple places? If not, global variables might do the trick.

Comment: The issue is that the variable represented in this example by `test` that I need access to is the JNIEnv that is passed to the JNI function. This issue is related to this other question i have open. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447454/call-a-function-in-java-from-c-outside-of-a-jni-function-android

Comment: As I understand, you only need it during load_config, i. e. you don't need Access after returning from your function. Why Not make a copy to global variable? Should also work for any data or pointer you get from jni...